# Запуск с нового hdd

Tags: windows, ubuntu, железо

Решил снять со своего ноута жесткий диск и переставить его на свой стационарый компьютер. Не в качестве флешки/накопителя, а чтоб запускал ОС. Но при старте компьютера выбивает окно "Hardware monitor..." где описывается вольтаж и ещё некоторые состояния системы.

На моём жестком диске стоит две ОС(Windows и Ubuntu), и если при старте его на ноуте выходило окно с выбором ОС которую нужно запустить, то на компьютере дальше окна "Hardware monitor..." не загружается. Как быть?

Comment: Ты всё правильно написал. Зачем указывать какая ось была на hdd? Просто накидаем тегов и будем ждать экстрасенсов, которые дадут универсальный ответ подходящий под любую ОС.

Comment: @donRumata не нашёл подходящих тегов, а вопрос на данный момент для меня очень срочный) может кто сталкивался)

Comment: @alexanderbarakin тут проблема немного в другом. Я же меняю целиком hdd с уже установленной ОС(в моём случае на диске стоит 2 ос WIndows и Ubuntu). Но они просто не подгружаются.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin обновил вопрос

Comment: вероятно, либо на носителе — uefi-загрузка, а компьютер этого не ожидает/не умеет, либо наоборот — на носителе «традиционная» mbr-загрузка, а компьютер опять таки этого не ожидает/не умеет. // если вы не знаете, как определить тип загрузки, приложите хотя бы вывод `$ sudo fdisk -l`, загрузившись с этого носителя.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin тип загрузки я видел в биосе, и на hdd если не ошибаюсь uefi. Получается что нужно будет просто изменить тип загрузки в boot menu? Так как команды в терминал врядли получится вывести.

Comment: подключите носитель к тому компьютеру, где с него можно осуществить загрузку, загрузите *gnu/linux*, выполните приведённую команду, её вывод (текст) скопируйте и приложите к вопросу.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin к сожалению не могу переставить обратно в ноут чтобы проверит, но помню что там был uefi и legacy. Но как мне заставить компьютер загружать данный носитель? мб какие то данные с биоса скинуть?

Comment: используйте компьютер, в котором есть uefi-загрузчик. переделать содержимое носителя «под mbr-загрузчик» — задача, насколько я понимаю, весьма нетривиальная и неоправданно трудоёмкая.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin а как узнать есть ли у меня uefi загрузчик на компьютере(в биосе это где то просматривается)?

Comment: учитывая, что [uefi предназначен для замены bios](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Firmware_Interface), «это» должно «просматриваться» очень хорошо. для сравнения просто загляните в настройки uefi-загрузчика в том компьютере, где данный носитель работал.

Comment: даже если в том компьтере, где носитель не работает, имеется именно uefi-загрузчик, в его настройках может быть: а) отключена uefi-загрузка в пользу т.н. «legacy-загрузки» (т.е., mbr-загрузки); б) заблокировано использование неподписанных uefi-загрузчиков с диска, а они по какой-то причине не подписаны (или подписаны «неправильно» с точки зрения uefi).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вообщем ребята, решение было следующим. Я просто перекинув hdd с ноута в комп, переустановил на нём ОС, и вуаля, всё заработало.